# Porque no se puede pasar un parametro al constructor cuando se usa el decorador @Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, spa

Cundo intento pasarle un parametro al constructor de clase me lanza un error : "Can't resolve all paremeters for Prueba c/:Users/....../prueba.component.ts:(?).

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector:"app-rueba",
    template: "hola"
})
export class Prueba
{
    n:string;
    constructor(nombre:string)
    {
      this.n=nombre;
    }
}
```

Porque se sucede esto??
PD: Disculpen si la respuesta es bastante obvia soy bastante nuevo en angular

Answer (score 1):

las variables en el constructor a declarar se tiene que colocar antes del nombre si
dicha variable va a ser privada o publica para los demás (fuera del propio componente.

```
constructor(private nombre:string) OR constructor(public nombre:string)
```